# Ethernet port not working

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm running 15.04. WiFi is working fine, ethernet not working at all. Have run `sudo lshw -C network` and this is my output:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
       version: 0a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

Comment: may we have the output of `nm-tool` look for an interface named eth0 or something similar

Comment: "No command 'nm-tool' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dm-tool' from package 'lightdm' (main)
nm-tool: command not found"
I'm running 15.04 if that's any help

Comment: I'm not familiar with 15.04 but try to find the network manager, this is the guy that tells you what interfaces are available.

Comment: If the correct driver didn't load automatically, something else is wrong. Let's try to load it and check the log: `sudo modprobe r8169` and then do: `dmesg | grep r8169`. Paste the result here: http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link in your response.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11551883/

Comment: Now you have an _eth0_ interface. Does it show up at the Network Manager icon, _Ethernet Network_ perhaps?

Comment: It does now. No longer showing as unclaimed either. Cheers old sport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver is not loading automatically. Let's fix it. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo r8169  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

You should be all set.